Constructing large pandas Dataframe results in missing index and col names
I'm constructing a big df out of multiple csv files. The only differences between those files should be slightly differing order of the col names. I stuck them in a recursive loop and put them into dfs. After some basic clean-up operations, I concatenated the multiple dfs and called pandas's to_csv method. The result is a df with apparently 45 columns, of which all are present in the data, yet two are missing both their index and their name when I call df.info(). It seems the two problematic columns are the only ones put into quotation marks by pandas, those being the last col "co2-ausstoß" (this one I can imagine being because of the weird character, though I'm not sure) and the col "additional", which I can refer to in my code with "additional\r" (while having another additional-column, without quotation marks, also present in df).
My code for reference (I omitted methods I ran on specific columns not referring to "co2-ausstoß" and "additional"):
Input:
autohero_data_list = []


for entry in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(entry, lineterminator='\n', sep=";", header=0)
    df = df[df.listing_price.notnull()]
    df = df[df.highlights.notnull()]
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace(' ','_')


   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    autohero_data_list.append(df)

df_clean_autohero = pd.concat(autohero_data_list)

path = "./data/data_cleaned"

df_clean_autohero.to_csv(os.path.join(path,r"autohero_data_clean"), encoding='utf-8', index=False)

df_clean_autohero.info()

Out:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 10173 entries, 0 to 108
Data columns (total 45 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   url                  10173 non-null  object 
 1   scrape_date          10173 non-null  object 
 2   make                 10173 non-null  object 
 3   model                10173 non-null  object 
 4   listing_price        10173 non-null  float64
 .
 .
 .
 35  highlights           10173 non-null  object 
 36  comfort              10173 non-null  object 
 37  multimedia           10170 non-null  object 
 38  light-and-sight      10165 non-null  object 
 39  security             10165 non-null  object 
          6837 non-null   object  
 41  co2-effizienzklasse  10173 non-null  object 
 42  additional           3330 non-null   object 
 43  verbrauch            1 non-null      object 
         119 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(4), object(41)
memory usage: 3.6+ MB

My issue is then of course at #40 and #44, and I don't understand what's wrong here. Also, you can see that there is another "additional" column in the df, as mentioned - for some reason, the "additional" columns, which contain a list of values, were not merged within the loop.
For the two columns containing "additional" in the col name, I tried finding out whether they were identical or possibly inverted, by calling df_new["additional\r"].isna().sum() and df_new["additional"].isna().sum(), yielding 3336 and 6843 as results, respectively. Finding the len(df_new) and summing up the two results from the previous methods reveals that the result is off by 6 entries - meaning that the two columns with "additional" in the name are not completely just inverted, though possibly close.
This is my first question here, so I hope I gave all relevant info, otherwise let me know what else I can provide. Any input or suggestion would be highly appreciated!
Edit: For now it seems to me like the problem is caused by some kind of encoding issue due to weird characters in the input files, combined with quoting of "read_csv" and "to_csv" methods of pandas. I have tried installing the "Gremlin" extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins&ssr=false#overview), though that doesn't seem to help any - at least it doesn't catch anything in my file, even with it being enabled globally.
Edit 2: Not sure if I solved my issue entirely, but it seems through brute-forcing encoding of each column string name to ascii by doing:
for col in df:
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
        if df[col].dtype == str:
            df[col] = df[col].str.decode('ascii')
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        pass

it seems to have worked, at least for now my df looks promising.
